# Meteor template won't reference event or method

Tags: javascript, email, templates, meteor

In meteor.js, I've having trouble connecting the HTML and the JS.  There's no reaction on the button click, and I don't see why not.  Therefore the meteor method in server isn't called, and no email is sent.
HTML:

```
<template name='confirmation'>
    <div class = "container" >
    <form role = "form" id = "email-form">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type= "email" class = "form-control" id = "inputEmail" placeholder = "Enter email">
        </div>
        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary"> Send mail</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

This code runs on the client:

```
 Template.confirmation.events({
  'submit #confirmation-form': function (e,t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toAddr=t.find('#inputEmail').value;
    var subject = ("Booked");
    var body = ("Thanks for booking")
    Meteor.call('sendEmail', toAddr, subj, text)
  }
  })
```

This code runs on the server:

```
    if (Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.startup(function(){

  process.env.MAIL_URL = "mailgun"
  Accounts.config({
    sendVerificationEmail: true
  })

  })
  Meteor.methods({
    'sendEmail': function(toAddr,subj,text){
      this.unblock();
      Email.Send({
        from: "booking@timesharewebapp.com",
        to:Meteor.toAddr,
        subject : subj,
        text: text
      })
    }
  })
}
```

The problem is that nothing will react when I press the button.  Nothing comes up in the console, or in the cmd prompt.  I don't know if it's the way I'm calling my events, or if it's the email function.

Comment: at a minimum, add a console.log() (or set a breakpoint) in your handler on the client to see if you're getting in there. divide and conquer!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong selector on the event. Try the below code.

```
Template.confirmation.events({
  'submit #email-form': function (e,t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toAddr=t.find('#inputEmail').value;
    var subject = ("Booked");
    var body = ("Thanks for booking")
    Meteor.call('sendEmail', toAddr, subj, text)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work, although this still didn't have the methods call each other, and I don't know why